# jQuery UI autocomplete examples

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm hoping someone can help with this, I'm having a real difficult time getting jQueryUI's autocomplete to work with ajax in a asp.net app (not MVC).  I can get it to make the ajax call but I'm not doing something right handling the response.

Just for starters I'm trying to have autocomplete make an ajax call to 'GetSuggestions.aspx' which will return a hard coded string.  I have it where it will make the call to GetSuggestions.aspx but I can't get it to return anything to the page. (My next step would be to have 'GetSuggestions.asxp' return a list of name/value pairs but I'll tackle that next).

I'm using the example from here:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote
with the exception of using 'source: "GetSuggestions.aspx" (instead of "search.php")

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for something similar and this example should help [TextBox AutoComplete with ASP.NET and jQuery UI](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=515)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an Asp.Net WebControl wrapping the JQuery UI autocomplete widget.
You can find it, together with documentation, at the following address:

http://autocompletedotnet.codeplex.com/

Hope it can help

Answer (score 0):

1.write the logics in GetSuggestions.asmx(webservice) instead of GetSuggestions.aspx
2.make your method public static return_type functionname(arglist){} in GetSuggestions.asmx
3.Refer your web service in your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    function log(message) {
        $("<div/>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
        $("#log").attr("scrollTop", 0);
    }

    $("#birds").autocomplete({
        source: "GetSuggestions.asmx",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            log(ui.item ? ("Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id) : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

if your web service is resides in root directory.

or else you can use ajax control toolkit(if you like).
Thanks.

Comment: Agree - not sure if you can call an ASPX page to perform a AJAX call in this context.

You'll either need an ASMX web service, a WCF web service, or a generic http handler (ASHX)

Comment: for a couple of reasons, I have to call 'GetSuggestions.aspx' (I have other ajax calls calling aspx pages...I just use Response.Write())

Comment: I'm now thinking that my problem is that my asp.net page isn't actually returning "json" data, I'm using the following code to return what I thought was JSON data:

JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
Country cty = new Country();
cty.Name = "Canada";
cty.Abbr = "CA";
Response.Write(js.Serialize(cty));

Will that work?

Comment: we can perform ajax operation with .aspx page,for that we need enable pagemthod property in script manager.and we should declare our method as webmethod.
so that we can access the server side methods from js

Answer (score 0):

One common problem returning XML (not sure with JSON) from Aspx page is the first **Enter** (NewLine) as the first character if you do not put the first line of the XML in the same than the page directives.

**Wrong way:**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" ... %>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MOResponse>
    <Id_Banco>MyBank</Id_Banco>
    <Id_Status>1</Id_Status>
    <Status>Success</Status>
</MOResponse>
```

**Right way:**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" ... %><?xml version="1.0"?>
<MOResponse>
    <Id_Banco>MyBank</Id_Banco>
    <Id_Status>1</Id_Status>
    <Status>Success</Status>
</MOResponse>
```